# Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

I want to persist a objects by using JPA in a MYSQL-database. Here ist my create script:

```
CREATE TABLE toolboxAccount (
idtoolboxAccount INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL  ,
password_2 VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(idtoolboxAccount));



CREATE TABLE config (
idconfig INT  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  ,
defaultExportPath VARCHAR(255)  NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(idconfig)  ,
INDEX config_FKIndex1(toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount),
FOREIGN KEY(toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount)
REFERENCES toolboxAccount(idtoolboxAccount)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE connection (
idconnection INT  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  ,
url VARCHAR(255)  NULL  ,
username VARCHAR(30)  NULL  ,
password_2 VARCHAR(30)  NULL  ,
site VARCHAR(30)  NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(idconnection)  ,
INDEX connection_FKIndex1(toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount),
FOREIGN KEY(toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount)
 REFERENCES toolboxAccount(idtoolboxAccount)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE export (
idexport INTEGER UNSIGNED  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
connection_idconnection INT  NOT NULL  ,
nameOfExportZIP VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL    ,
PRIMARY KEY(idexport)  ,
INDEX export_FKIndex1(connection_idconnection),
FOREIGN KEY(connection_idconnection)
REFERENCES connection(idconnection)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

**The classes are**

---

ToolboxaccountEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "toolboxaccount", schema = "", catalog = "toolboxtest")
public class ToolboxaccountEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
private long idtoolboxAccount;
private String username;
private String password_2;



@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private ConfigEntity configEntity;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<ConnectionEntity> connections;

public List<ConnectionEntity> getConnections() {
    return connections;
}

public void setConnections(List<ConnectionEntity> connections) {
    this.connections = connections;
}
...
```

ConnectionEnity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "connection", schema = "", catalog = "toolboxtest")
public class ConnectionEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq",sequenceName="MY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
private long idconnection;
private String url;
private String username;
private String password_2;
private String site;


@Column(name = "idconnection")
public long getIdconnection() {
    return idconnection;
}

public void setIdconnection(int idconnection) {
    this.idconnection = idconnection;
}
...
```

---

The persisting of ToolboxAccountEntity works but when I add a ConnectionEntity I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`toolboxtest`.`connection`, CONSTRAINT `connection_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount`) REFERENCES `toolboxaccount` (`idtoolboxAccount`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO toolboxtest.connection (PASSWORD_2, SITE, URL, USERNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [4 parameters bound]
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) If you want to make a insert operation, make sure that the record doesnt exists in the Database.

2) If you want to make an update operation, make sure that the record exist in the database.

3) Remember that the records has to be well relationships, primary key, foreign key.

That kind of error, is very common when a record already exists.

Regards! Tell us if you correct your issue

Comment: Hello and thx for you answer, I deleted the tables and recreated it and now I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'toolboxAccount_idtoolboxAccount' doesn't have a default value... Should not be the "idtoolboxAccount" added as a Foreign-Key?

Comment: Well.. toolboxAccount.idtoolboxAccount this is your primary key of your table, its not receiving any value. Did you miss to insert a value to that primary key?? However, if its autoincremental, you dont have to insert any values, the system will do for you.

Comment: I'dont want to insert a value for that primary key because I want that this is automatically done so I set AUTO_INCREMENT. I tried another thing by adding a primary key but I got the same error

Comment: Check the tables, and check if you are inserting a record that has the correct relationship in your code. At the moment, i cannot tell you much more..